# Authenticate the Open function in python to create a file using Usename and Password

Tags: python, python-2.6

When I tried to create file to a shared folder I got an error **Permission denied: '** tp create the file. I know a different username and password to create the file in that share folder. How can I use it with the Open function.
The Open function I used is as given below.

```
with open(rootDirectory+"\\"+"test.txt", "a") as NewFile:
NewFile.write(filedata);
```

Thanks,

Comment: You can't do this with the `open` function. So if doing it with the `open` function is an essential part of your question, that's your answer.

Comment: As a side note, it's much better to use `os.path.join` than to try to concatenate paths manually like this.

Comment: Thank you abarnert.
Is there any other function available to do this?

Answer (score 2):

There is no magical way to change the way you call `open` to do this for you. You have to interact with the Win32 security system in some way.

---

The first option is to [impersonate the other user](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376391%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Then, anything you do—including `open`, or anything else—is done as if you were that user. If you have [`pywin32`](http://pywin32.sourceforge.net), you can use its [`win32security`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.3/pywin32/win32security.html) wrappers to do this. You should read the MSDN docs on [`LogonUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [`LogonUserEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378189%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and [`ImpersonateLoggedOnUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378612%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to understand how this works. But it will look something like this:

```
user = LogonUser(username, None, password, 
                 LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT)
try:
    ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(user)
    with open(rootDirectory+"\\"+"test.txt", "a") as NewFile:
        NewFile.write(filedata)
finally:
    RevertToSelf()
    CloseHandler(user)
```

Of course you probably want some error handling, and you might want to create some context-manager wrappers instead of using a `finally` block, and so on. And again, read the docs to decide which function you want to call and which arguments you want to pass. But this should get you started.

---

As a variation on this, you can run a child process as that other user. That doesn't require impersonation (which you may not have the `SeImpersonatePrivilege` privileges to do). It's also much easier to port to Unix if you ever need to do that. See [`CreateProcessWithLogon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682431%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for details.

A simpler way to do the same thing is to not do it from Python, but from the shell. Launch your script with the [RunAs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms717801%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) command instead of launching it directly. Or, if you can't do that, take the part that needs to run as the other user, move it into another script, then `subprocess` the `RunAs` command to launch it.

---

Alternatively, if you have sufficient rights (or can elevate to Administrator privileges to *get* those rights), you can just change the ACLs on the file to give yourself the write permission you don't have. In some cases, just doing `os.chmod` is sufficient for that, but usually not; you will have to pywin32 the native Win32 APIs again.